# android progressbar on click of Home/Back button

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I have implemnted progressbar in my small game like below

```
    gameProgressBar =(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.GameProcess);

    thrd = new Thread(progressBarThread);
    thrd.start();

}

//Progress bar function
private Runnable progressBarThread = new Runnable(){

    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (GameProgressCount<60){  //60 = 1 minute
            try{
                myHandle.sendMessage(myHandle.obtainMessage());
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
            catch(Throwable t){
            }
        }
        thrd.stop();
    }

    Handler myHandle = new Handler(){

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                GameProgressCount++;
                gameProgressBar.setProgress(GameProgressCount);
        }
    };
```

My question is that when i click on back/home button of the device, app is getting minimized (or goes previous screen) but the Progress bar thread would be running in the background. is it possible to pause the thread and resume when i minimize/open the app screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pause the Thread in the OnPause method of the Activity and you can resume the Thread on OnResume method of the Activity which is pretty stright forward. Now if you wanted to Keep the GameProgressCount intact and wanted to Resume back from where it has left then you can use SharedPreference to store the value, when you resume back use the same value to start with.

Comment: in this case, App is still active but minimized, is it really required to save the state in sharedpreference ?

Comment: If you press Home key Activity remains in the stack and if you press back button activity will be killed. so onPause is the method which will be called in both the cases so you can pause the thread there. and sharedPreference is only for storing values if you wanted to resume the activity from where it left, otherwise not needed